# Using csv.DictWriter to write a dictionary's {'key':value} pairs into a .csv file and get " ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '

Tags: python, bash, csv, dictionary

I am using Bash to generate the output of a python script. A dictionary in Bash looks like following, which I found very confusing:

```
error = [('Connection to DB failed', 14), ('Permission denied while closing ticket', 11), ('The ticket was modified while updating', 10), ("Ticket doesn't exist", 8), ('Timeout while retrieving information', 16), ('Tried to add information to closed ticket', 13)]
```

It kept throwing me off because a dictionary in a python IDE looks like:

```
{'a':2, 'b':3, 'as':32, 'bb':13, 'da':32, 'vb':53}
```

I am using the code below to store the dictionary keys and values from **'error'** into a file called **'error_message.csv'**.

```
keys1 = ['Error','Count']
    
with open('error_message.csv', 'w+') as file:
   writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=keys1)
   writer.writeheader()
   writer.writerows([error])
```

The error I keep receiving is:

```
raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Timeout while retrieving information', 'Permission denied while closing ticket', 'Tried to add information to closed ticket', 'The ticket was modified while updating', 'Connection to DB failed', "Ticket doesn't exist"
```

It seems to me that **csv.DictWriter** thinks that the first 2 entries of the dictionary i.e.

```
('Connection to DB failed', 14) 
('Permission denied while closing ticket', 11)
```

are the fields associated with the **fieldnames ['Error', 'Count']**. This means that csv.DictWriter thinks that:

```
'Error' = ('Connection to DB failed', 14) and
'Count' = ('Permission denied while closing ticket', 11)
```

I have tried many variations of this code (including just using a simple csv.writer to write each key,value pair), one of which is as follows:

```
keys1 = ['Error','Count']

with open('error_message.csv', 'w+') as file:
   writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=keys1)
   writer.writeheader()
   for data in error:
      writer.writerow(data)
```

With this particular code, I get the following error:

```
wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys
```

I am not sure where am I making the mistake. The following code creates the error_message.csv file.

```
with open('syslog.log') as file:
        for row in file:
                row.strip()
                echeck = re.findall(r'ERROR', row)
                
                if 'ERROR' in echeck:
                        echeck=re.split(r'[ ()]', row)
                        
                        user=echeck[-2]
                        user.strip()
                        
                        if user not in per_user:
                           per_user[user]=1
                        per_user[user]+=1
                        
                        echeck=re.split(r'[ERROR()]',row)
                        errors=echeck[-3].strip()
                        
                        if errors not in error:
                           error[errors]=1
                        error[errors]+=1
```

The 'syslog.log' file contains systems logs which looks like the following:

```
Jan 31 00:09:39 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#4217] (mdouglas)
Jan 31 00:16:25 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#1754] (noel)
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (breee)
Jan 31 00:44:34 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (ac)
Jan 31 01:00:50 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#4709] (blossom)
Jan 31 01:29:16 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#6518] (rr.robinson)
Jan 31 01:33:12 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (mcintosh)
Jan 31 01:43:10 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (jackowens)
Jan 31 01:49:29 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (mdouglas)
Jan 31 02:30:04 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (oren)
Jan 31 02:55:31 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (xlg)
Jan 31 03:05:35 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 03:08:55 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (blossom)
Jan 31 03:39:27 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (bpacheco)
Jan 31 03:47:24 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (enim.non)
Jan 31 04:30:04 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (rr.robinson)
Jan 31 04:31:49 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (oren)
Jan 31 04:32:49 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (mcintosh)
Jan 31 04:44:23 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 04:44:46 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (jackowens)
Jan 31 04:49:28 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (flavia)
Jan 31 05:12:39 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (oren)
Jan 31 05:18:45 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (sri)
Jan 31 05:23:14 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#1097] (breee)
Jan 31 05:35:00 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (nonummy)
Jan 31 05:45:30 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7115] (noel)
Jan 31 05:51:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (flavia)
Jan 31 05:57:46 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#2253] (nonummy)
Jan 31 06:12:02 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (oren)
Jan 31 06:26:38 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (xlg)
Jan 31 06:32:26 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7298] (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 06:36:25 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (flavia)
Jan 31 06:57:00 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (jackowens)
Jan 31 06:59:57 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#7255] (oren)
Jan 31 07:59:56 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (flavia)
Jan 31 08:01:40 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (jackowens)
Jan 31 08:03:19 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#1712] (britanni)
Jan 31 08:22:37 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#2860] (mcintosh)
Jan 31 08:28:07 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (montanap)
Jan 31 08:49:15 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (britanni)
Jan 31 08:50:50 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (montanap)
Jan 31 09:04:27 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (noel)
Jan 31 09:15:41 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (oren)
Jan 31 09:18:47 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#8385] (mdouglas)
Jan 31 09:28:18 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#2452] (jackowens)
Jan 31 09:41:16 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (ac)
Jan 31 10:11:35 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (blossom)
Jan 31 10:21:36 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (montanap)
Jan 31 11:04:02 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (breee)
Jan 31 11:19:37 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (sri)
Jan 31 11:22:06 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (montanap)
Jan 31 11:31:34 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 11:40:25 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (mai.hendrix)
Jan 31 11:47:07 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#4562] (ac)
Jan 31 11:58:33 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 12:00:17 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7897] (kirknixon)
Jan 31 12:02:49 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (mai.hendrix)
Jan 31 12:20:23 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (kirknixon)
Jan 31 12:20:40 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (flavia)
Jan 31 12:24:32 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#5784] (sri)
Jan 31 12:50:10 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (blossom)
Jan 31 12:58:16 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (nonummy)
Jan 31 13:08:10 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#8685] (rr.robinson)
Jan 31 13:48:45 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (breee)
Jan 31 14:13:00 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#4225] (noel)
Jan 31 14:38:50 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (enim.non)
Jan 31 14:41:18 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (xlg)
Jan 31 14:45:55 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#7948] (noel)
Jan 31 14:50:41 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#8628] (noel)
Jan 31 14:56:35 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (noel)
Jan 31 15:27:53 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (blossom)
Jan 31 15:28:15 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (enim.non)
Jan 31 15:44:25 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#7333] (enim.non)
Jan 31 16:17:20 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#1653] (noel)
Jan 31 16:19:40 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (mdouglas)
Jan 31 16:24:31 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#5455] (ac)
Jan 31 16:35:46 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (oren)
Jan 31 16:53:54 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#3813] (mcintosh)
Jan 31 16:54:18 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (bpacheco)
Jan 31 17:15:47 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (mcintosh)
Jan 31 17:29:11 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (oren)
Jan 31 17:51:52 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#8604] (mcintosh)
Jan 31 18:09:17 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (noel)
Jan 31 18:43:01 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (nonummy)
Jan 31 19:00:23 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (blossom)
Jan 31 19:20:22 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (mai.hendrix)
Jan 31 19:59:06 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#6361] (enim.non)
Jan 31 20:02:41 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (xlg)
Jan 31 20:21:55 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#7159] (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 20:28:26 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (breee)
Jan 31 20:35:17 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7737] (nonummy)
Jan 31 20:48:02 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (mdouglas)
Jan 31 20:56:58 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#4372] (oren)
Jan 31 21:00:23 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#2389] (sri)
Jan 31 21:02:06 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (breee)
Jan 31 21:20:33 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#3297] (kirknixon)
Jan 31 21:29:24 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (blossom)
Jan 31 22:58:55 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#2461] (jackowens)
Jan 31 23:25:18 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#9876] (blossom)
Jan 31 23:35:40 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#5896] (mcintosh)
```

I am using regex to find the word **'ERROR'** in each row contained in the **'syslog.log'** file. From all such rows, I proceed to extract the error message as well as the username for the user who generated the error.

The **error={}** dictionary stores all the different error names whereas the **per_user={}** dictionary stores all the different usernames who generated an **ERROR**.

Comment: It seems that `error_message.csv` has 'Connection to DB failed' etc as column headings.  Can you show the contents of the file, and how it is created?

Comment: Just made the update there. Thanks @snakecharmerb

Answer (score 0):

From the Python DictWriter documentation found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

> Create an object which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output rows. The `fieldnames` parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method are written to file f. The optional `restval` parameter specifies the value to be written if the dictionary is missing a key in fieldnames. If the dictionary passed to the writerow() method contains a key not found in fieldnames, the optional `extrasaction` parameter indicates what action to take. If it is set to 'raise', the default value, a ValueError is raised. If it is set to 'ignore', extra values in the dictionary are ignored. Any other optional or keyword arguments are passed to the underlying writer instance.

Thus the `fieldnames` parameter is the keys that will be contained in the dictionary that'll be passed to writerow. Because you passed in a dictionary that contains extra keys other than `Error` and `Count`, an error was thrown. I recommend you use a library like pandas if you have dynamic columns.

Comment: Thanks Omar. I thought the dictionary only had two keys i.e. 'Error' and 'Count'. Isn't it so, since all the 'error' dictionary members contain key,value pairs that have 1-to-1 relationship i.e ONLY one value for ONE key.

Answer (score 0):

The `error` dictionary is, in terms of your csv, `value:value` rather than `key:value`.  Your code only needs a small modification to work with this structure: use a [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) rather than a [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and treat the dictionary entries as rows to be added to the csv.

```py
with open('error_message.csv', 'w+') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(keys1)
    for errmsg, count in error.items():
        writer.writerow([errmsg, count])
```

One small style tip: you can skip checking to see if a key exists in the counter dictionaries by using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
import collections

error = collections.defaultdict(int)
per_user = collections.defaultdict(int)

with open('syslog.log') as file:
    for row in file:
        row.strip()
        echeck = re.findall(r'ERROR', row)

        if 'ERROR' in echeck:
            echeck = re.split(r'[ ()]', row)

            user = echeck[-2]
            user.strip()

            per_user[user] += 1

            echeck = re.split(r'[ERROR()]', row)
            errors = echeck[-3].strip()

            error[errors] += 1
```

This also exposes a fault in the original logic - for a new entry it would set `error[errors] = 1` and then immediately increment it, so the first entry would be counted twice.